# php how to output arabic characters on windows using powershell

Tags: php, moodle

I have the below PHP script

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$file = "//192.168.10.206/wwwroot/SABIS CORPORATE/PrepList/Documents/41/1516 Level I Arabic Basic Questions and Answers T1 الأسلوب الخبري.pdf"; 
echo $file; 
?>
```

and the result is always

```
PS C:\Users\aaoun> php -q c:\Users\aaoun\Desktop\Test-AAA.php
//192.168.10.206/wwwroot/SABIS CORPORATE/PrepList/Documents/41/1516 Level I Arabic Basic Questions and Answers T1 ╪د┘╪ث
╪│┘┘ê╪ذ ╪د┘╪«╪ذ╪▒┘è.pdf PS C:\Users\aaoun>
```

I tried **UT8 encoding**

```
iconv("unicode", "utf-8", $file);    
iconv("Latin1_General_CI_AS","utf-8",$file); 
iconv("Arabic_CI_AS","utf-8",$file); 
base64_encode($file); 
utf8_encode($file);     
base64_decode($file); 
utf8_decode($file);  
iconv('WINDOWS-1256', 'UTF-8', $file);   
iconv('cp1256', 'UTF-8', $file);
```

Nothing seems to work, I keep getting wrong text I need to get the text to check if the file exists ...

Comment: `echo file_exists("your_filename");`

Comment: / / 1 9 2 . 1 6 8 . 1 0 . 2 0 6 / w w w r o o t / S A B I S   C O R P O R A T E / P r e p L i s t / D o c u m e n t s /
 4 1 / 1 5 1 6   L e v e l   I   A r a b i c   B a s i c   Q u e s t i o n s   a n d   A n s w e r s   T 1  ♠'♠D♠#♠3♠D♠H
♠(  ♠'♠D♠.♠(♠1♠J . p d fPHP Warning:  file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given in C:\Users\aao
un\Desktop\Test-AAA.php on line 6

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the encoding of the file-system is the same as the encoding of the string that contains the file-name in your PHP code.

Otherwise you're testing for the wrong file to exist.

For example, if your file-system does not support UTF-8 but the file-name is encoded in UTF-8. As you are using Windows, it is worth noting that Windows filesystems (FAT, FAT32, NTFS) are not UTF-8 aware.  you can convert your file name to UTF-16 like

```
$newName = mb_convert_encoding('your file path', 'UTF-16', 'UTF-8');
```

If that does not work, you can use `urlencode`. All characters returned from urlencode are valid in filenames (NTFS/HFS/UNIX).

```
$newName = urlencode($file);
```

Try this code to know if the file exists:

```
if (file_exists('your file path')) {   
//file exists;                         
}
else
{
//Does not exist
}
```

Comment: If I open the url I can find the file,

Comment: @user5514667 can you add the implementation of how you are using this method in your question?

Comment: <?php
if (file_exists('//192.168.10.206/wwwroot/SABIS CORPORATE/PrepList/Documents/41/1516 Level I Arabic Basic Questions and Answers T1 الأسلوب الخبري.pdf')) {   
 echo "true";
}
else
{
 echo "false";
} 
?>

Comment: If the file name does not contain arabic letter the result will be true

Comment: Yes this happens when encoding of file path is not same as encoding of file system. That returns a wrong path and hence wrong results. What file system do you use? NTFS or FAT32?

Comment: The server file system is NTFS

Comment: NTFS might accept UTF 16 encoded file name. But it will definitely not pick UTF 8 encoded ones.

Comment: <?php
$file = '//192.168.10.206/wwwroot/SABIS CORPORATE/PrepList/Documents/41/1516 Level I Arabic Basic Questions and Answers T1 الأسلوب الخبري.pdf';
// $text = iconv("utf-16","utf-8",$file);
$text = mb_convert_encoding($file, 'UTF-16', 'UTF-8');
echo $text;
if (file_exists($text)) {   
 echo "true";
}
else
{
 echo "false";
} 
?>

Comment: <?php
$file = '//192.168.10.206/wwwroot/SABIS CORPORATE/PrepList/Documents/41/1516 Level I Arabic Basic Questions and Answers T1 الأسلوب الخبري.pdf';
// $text = iconv("utf-16","utf-8",$file);
$text = mb_convert_encoding($file, 'UTF-16', 'UTF-8');
echo $text;
if (file_exists($text)) {   
 echo "true";
}
else
{
 echo "false";
} 
?>

Comment: file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path,

Comment: NSNoob: Thanks for your help,.. Any other thoughts ?

Comment: @user5514667 you can use `urlencode ($file )` All characters returned from urlencode are valid in filenames (NTFS/HFS/UNIX), then you can just urldecode the filenames back to UTF-8 (or whatever encoding they were in).

Comment: After encoding the file, checking if the file exists return False.

Comment: Well the answer to your original question is the same. You have another problem now, how to read files with Arabic names. I don't think I have any more ideas to fix that.